# How to show full column name in Tidyverse R

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is an odd question. I have a dataframe in R that that I read in and I want to see the full names of the columns, not the truncated ones. How can i show the full name?

This is the output i get. I don't know how to get rid of the ...

I just read in a csv file with headers.

movies <- read.csv("Movies.csv")

```
> colnames(movies)
 [1] "Day.of.Week"            "Director"               "Genre"                  "Movie.Title"            "Release.Date"           "Studio"                 "Adjusted.Gross...mill."
 [8] "Budget...mill."         "Gross...mill."          "IMDb.Rating"            "MovieLens.Rating"       "Overseas...mill."       "Overseas."              "Profit...mill."        
[15] "Profit."                "Runtime..min."          "US...mill."             "Gross...US"
```

Comment: What is the full name of the column.  if you read with `read.csv`, you can use `check.names = FALSE`

Comment: Some have spaces and whatnot. I just wanted to see the full names listed. I tried head(), names(), and colnames() and they all truncate some of the long column names in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While reading with `read.csv/read.table`, we can specify the option `check.names = FALSE` (by default, it is `TRUE`)

```
movies <- read.csv("movies.csv", check.names = FALSE)
```